# If i click on edit button particular row data should be fetch in listview?

Tags: android

I want to fetch record through id from database?
I want to edit the whole record from database if i click on edit button in listview row.

Comment: show code you have tried

Comment: What you have implemented yet???

Comment: I have creaed database and designing.....delete operation is done now i want to do edit operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out code I can not help you but I think you do not have the direction or road map . let me show you the road map so that you know how to achieve what you want to do :

1. implement the click listener on list view. the click should be according to your need such as simple click or a long press or you get set item click listener.
2. In click listner you can get the index easily and use index to get the item Id from the model class (if you have custom adapter and array )
3. now you have the index you got the Id , and Id is the key in the database to get the Data from the row. so You have id you can get the data and show that data into the activity where user can edit those values

   this is just the demo code so that you can get the idea , in my case I have this function in Database And I was getting/ retrieving the array list in the following manner

   public ArrayList GetData(String Name)  {

   > ```
   >   ArrayList<Detail> list = new ArrayList<Detail>();
   >     cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from MosqueDataNew where Name = '"
   >             + Name + "'", null);
   >     if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   >         cursor.moveToFirst();
   >         list.add(new Detail(
   >                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")),
   >                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")),
   >                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LatitudeLocation")),
   >                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LongitudeLocation")),
   >                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Size"))));
   >         return list;
   >     }
   >     return null;
   > }
   > ```

so this is the way to get the idea to how to retrieve data from the specific row.

5. Now after getting the editions from the user you can save the values again at the same id so to update the data for this you have to implement the update method in the database. and call that function the Update button click listener.

public boolean UpdateData(ContentValues contentValues, String id) {

```
if (db.update("YourTableName", contentValues, "ID = '" + id + "'",      null) > 0) {
return true;
}
return false;}
```

content values are the new updated values you want to save in that place.

**Part 2**
As You want to edit the values in new activity by clicking on the button of each row , you can achieve it  the way if you pass the context to the adapter while creating it, because for opening new activity which you want to use for editing the values, You must have context to start a new activity , this is how you can do it :

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {
     private Context context;

     public MyAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;     
     }

     public View getView(...){
         View v;
         v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             void onClick() {
                 context.startActivity(...);
             }
         });
     }
}
```

so as you can see in this you are using to start the activity you wanted to open , so it is clear now how to navigate to new activity , but before doing this you need to get all of the data from database to edit, so this is how you do in button click before opening the new activity

In your getView method of adapter you have to put your click listener which would work for each row , you need to get the id of your item list and then pass it on to database function which is getting all the data for specific Id

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //get id of itemlist , or array what ever datamodel you are using  and use it to fetch the data from the database

            }
        });
```

> Edit Part 3

If you want to get the data on basis of id then upper defined function of database would be changed a little bit, here is hows it goes

```
public ArrayList GetData(String id) {

  ArrayList<Detail> list = new ArrayList<Detail>();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from MosqueDataNew where id = '"
            + ID + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        list.add(new Detail(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LatitudeLocation")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LongitudeLocation")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Size"))));
        return list;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Update part 5**

as you have made the method to get all the data from the database now if you need to get the specific row you need to just changed the query

```
// get userlist
    public List<UserList> getuserlistRow(String id) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT firstname , lastname"
                + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * From YOUR_TABLE_NAME where id="'id'"", null);
        List<UserList> userlist = new ArrayList<UserList>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserList list = new UserList();
                list.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                list.setFirstname(cursor.getString(3));
                list.setLastname(cursor.getString(4));
                userlist.add(list);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return userlist;

    }
```

> now on button click , you can do this  ArrayList  myList =
>   new ArrayList(getuserlistRow(id));
>   Toast.makText(your_context,""+myList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show():

**Note**

> the above lines and shared code may have syntax error I have just given you the idea ,you can search the syntax on internet easily.

so in this way you are getting all the the data in a complete record , this method is returning data in a array list of of my data type which is "Detail" in my case , you can cast into your data type.

I hope this helps you in understanding how to do that.

Comment: if you have button in listview , then its easy , in adapter , get the button intiallized in the getview of adapter and then , you can get the id there as I said above on long click of list , you can also get the id from there too

Comment: i m not able to get id of particular row from database.

Comment: i have implemented baseadapter.

Comment: i want to Retrieve data using Key_RowId from database.

Comment: mHolder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
      
    
     Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
     
    
     
    
    
     Toast.makeText(mContext,"" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /*   Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,AdminEditActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     mContext.startActivity(intent);
    */ 
   }
  });

Comment: you want to fetch the record and then want to show in next activity ??

Comment: I am updating my answer as part two of your question

Comment: update my answer please mark it as a answer if it helps you

Comment: I have already used base adapter and now i want to fetch id from database so i can used action on edit button. i have used intent to go in next activity... EditActivity.java

Comment: so whats the problem Have you seen my eidetd answer too ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and I think its complete now and full of information  now your problem should have been solved

Comment: I will suggest you to improve your knowledge about android and OOP

Comment: give me u r mail id...i will send u my prj. if possible then plz do it.

Comment: I think it is not allowed here , and I do not see any rules anything about it

Comment: @MustafaBharatwala I think the answer is giving 100 % answer of the question you asked , though it seems that you have failed in implementing it due to lack of programming skills. But believe me do not hesitate to accept this as an Accepted answer.

Comment: one question when i click on listview in button how to print particular user list row name and id using toast ?? plz help me ??

Comment: update your code of  what you have done now ,,,,,,,,,,, so far

Comment: custombaseadapter.java

Comment: see my code i have implemented now i want when i click on view button the particular id & firstname should be print using toast from databse.then i have created viewactivity...in which whole data should be display of particular user.

Comment: public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id.size();
    } 
why are you dong this

Comment: well the code you shared is not related , you need to make the function in Database , then this would apply in the following code segment

Comment: Simply now i want to get particular id n name print in listview..using toast....when i click to button. for eg 1 abc xyz....click on button the id would be 1 n name abc using toast.

Comment: if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
     
     for(int i=0 ;    ;i++){
      UserList userList=new UserList();
      userList.setId(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID));
      userList.setFirstname(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.FIRSTNAME)));
      userList.setLastname(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.LASTNAME)));
      arrayList.add(userList);
     }

Comment: can u tell me wht shld i add in for condition to add data in listview using cursor ???

Comment: what do you mean in listview

Comment: private void displayData() {
  db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
    + DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null);
  userId.clear();
  user_fName.clear();
  user_lName.clear();

Comment: if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
     for(int i=0 ; i >   ;i++){
      UserList userList=new UserList();
      userList.setId(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID));
      userList.setFirstname(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.FIRSTNAME)));
      userList.setLastname(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.LASTNAME)));
      arrayList.add(userList);
     }
   } while (mCursor.moveToNext()); 
  }
  CustomBaseAdapter disadpt= new CustomBaseAdapter(this, arrayList);
  userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
  mCursor.close();
 }

Comment: I have made display() function to display data. i have added my code...see below.

Comment: i have create login & registration page...after registration i have created admin page in which i want to show user list who have registered. (ID,FirstName,Lastname)....in which i have added two button (EDIT,VIEW).When i click to edit button in particular row in listview the new activity will open in which particular data should ne fetch...i have already performed delete operation using id.

Comment: now i m not able to show list of user &i want to perform edit and view operation in list view.

Comment: problem solved of list user now only left is EDIT VIEW & DELETE.